# Duplicate Orders

Tags: magento-1.7

I am getting suddenly a strange error. Every order I am receiving is making duplicates for the same customer looks like it is the same order. What can be an issue. Its very wired to delete the duplicates again and again, the first one went through the payment gateways and the duplicates are only displaying. The duplicates are created again and again for after a small time, looks like a loop is running after a fixed time.

Edit:Another thing is all the orders are duplicting, not the last one and the time is not fixed, sometimes after a mint or 2 mints or 3 mints.

Comment: Does it happen with the different payment methods or all with the same?

Comment: currently seen for some payment methods because the customers are using that, but looks like duplicating for all. because we have disable one by one and still its duplicating.

Comment: I never heard of this issue. You can hook into the order save method and just log the request and everything of the environment to know when it happens. The next step is to check, where it happens. And as always: reporduction is the key.

Comment: [Debug debug debug](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) - follow the instructions [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) (specifically about disabling modules), testing your order creation between each change.

Comment: Test the speed to see how long it takes for the order to place once the user clicks the final order button. On very slow sites it can be the user re-clicking because it is taking so long to process.

Comment: Find workaround in http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48607/same-customer-places-duplicate-order/48799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted our server administrator and one of our port is closed and email was not sending. As we opened the port the duplicates stops. So as the port is closed the code is trying to create the order again and again when the code fails on email function.

Comment: Im also facing same issue. Can you tell me which port we have to open?